# Can't scroll in my iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm pretty new in creating iOS applications and currently I'm following Apple's starter tutorial.

[image: The application so far]

They suggest simulating on iPhone 6 which has a pretty big screen and therefore all the content fit its screen, however I'm simulating on iPhone 4 which has a smaller screen. All the content don't fit and I can't see all of the placeholder image. I'd expect that I would automatically be able to scroll so I'm able to view all the content but no.

[image: iPhone 4 simulator]

Comment: are you designed inside scrollview or it s a normal view

Comment: Your `UIScrollView` will only scroll if you have defined it's `contentSize` in code or using constraints in Interface Builder in which the `UIScrollView` can calculate its `contentSize` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have designed your contents on normal view. Instead you have to use `UIScrollView` which will allow you to scroll to see all your contents. `contentSize` property is important for this.

Refer Here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/

> The UIScrollView class provides support for displaying content that is
>   larger than the size of the application’s window. It enables users to
>   scroll within that content by making swiping gestures, and to zoom in
>   and back from portions of the content by making pinching gestures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll looking in to this and how it works.